# The outcome distribution of an algorithm generating random sample

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I am given an algorithm to generate the random sample of particular distribution and I am asked to find what the distribution we are sampling is.

The algorithm is as follows:

```
Draw U~Uni(0,1)
Repeat
Draw X~Uni(0,1)
Until U<X
Return X
```

and generally it boils down to drawing `X~Uni(U,1)`, because we reject everything that is smaller than `U`.

My approach was to find CDF. And I tried to play with conditional probabilities etc. but it took me nowhere close to the answer. It was more or less like this.

Notice $\mathbb{P}(X<t)\neq0$ only if $\mathbb{P}(U<t)=1$. Now, $\mathbb{P}(U<t)=t$ and $\mathbb{P}(U>t)=1-t$.
Whence
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X<t)&= \mathbb{P}(X<t  \quad\text{and} \quad U<t) + \mathbb{P}(X<t \quad \text{and} \quad U>t) = \mathbb{P}(X<t \quad \text{and} \quad U<t)
\\&=\mathbb{P}(X<t \ \big{|} \  U<t)\mathbb{P}(U<t)
\end{align}

The answer is $X \sim d$ where $d(x)=-log(1-x)$.

I don't have a clue how to deal with such type of problem. Is my approach with finding CDF right?
How should one tackle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. One indeed needs to play with conditional probabilities, but instead of looking for CDF should rather use the law of total probabilitiy.

Notice in fact it is not $X$ that has $Uni(U,1)$ distribution but rather a new "conditional variable" $Z=(X \big{|} U=t) \sim Uni(t,1)$ and therefore by the law of the total probability one has:
$f_X(x)=\int f_{X | U}(x|t)f_U(t)dt=\int_0^x\frac{1}{1-t}dt=-\log(1-x)$